# SQL - Invalid user.table.column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL statmenet

```
SELECT   COUNT('Oprettet af Initialer') AS meetings_booked,
         Dato salgstrin,
         VTEAM.TEAM
FROM     KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR POT 
         RIGHT JOIN KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO VTEAM ON VTEAM.DATO = POT.'Dato salgstrin'
WHERE    exists (SELECT 1 FROM KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO WHERE KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR.'Oprettet af Initialer' = KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO.INITIALER)
AND      'Salgstri' NOT IN('01 - Muligt emne','02 - Aktivt emne')
AND      'Oprettet dato' BETWEEN '2013-09-04' AND '2013-09-04'
GROUP BY 'Dato salgstrin' 'Oprettet af Initialer', VTEAM.TEAM
ORDER BY 'Dato salgstrin'
```

Now when ever i try to run this i get the following error:

```
Invalid user.table.column, table.colum, or column specification
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how i can fix it?

**Images of the tables**

KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR:

[image: table1]

KS_DRIFT.VTEAM_DATO:

[image]

Comment: Is `salgstrin` an alias for `Dato`? What db is this?

Comment: You shold explein us what is `Dato`, `salgstrin` and `Oprettet af Initialer`

Comment: this is an oracle database and no 'Data salgstrin' is a row and 'Salgstri' is a row aswell

Comment: Those are just rows like for instance in a user table you have username and password.

Comment: Can you describe `KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR` and `KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO` ?

Comment: @Parado il update my question with a picture of the two tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column (and table) names need to be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes. Single quotes are for string literals ("values").

`'Oprettet af Initialer'` is a string, `"Oprettet af Initialer"` is a column name

So you probably want:

```
SELECT   COUNT("Oprettet af Initialer") AS meetings_booked,
         "Dato salgstrin",
         VTEAM.TEAM
FROM     KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR POT 
         RIGHT JOIN KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO VTEAM ON VTEAM.DATO = POT."Dato salgstrin"
WHERE    exists (SELECT 1 FROM KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO WHERE KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR."Oprettet af Initialer" = KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO.INITIALER)
AND      "Salgstri" NOT IN ('01 - Muligt emne','02 - Aktivt emne')
AND      "Oprettet dato" BETWEEN '2013-09-04' AND '2013-09-04'
GROUP BY "Dato salgstrin", "Oprettet af Initialer", VTEAM.TEAM
ORDER BY "Dato salgstrin"
```

Please see the manual for more details on this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#i27561

**Edit**

Your subselect has another error:

`KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR."Oprettet af Initialer"` and `KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO.INITIALER` are invalid column references. There is one element too much in there. Column references are always in the form `tableName.columnName` or `tableAlias.ColumnName`. They never have three elements. I'm not sure which of them is incorrect in your case.

**Edit 2**

Listing "Oprettet af Initialer" in the GROUP BY clause seems a bit strange as you are using that column also as part of an aggregate function (inside the count).

---

A side note on your DATE values: specifying a date like this `'2013-09-04'` is subject to implict data type conversion and whether or not that works depends on the NLS settings of the client software you are working with - On my computer that format would generate an error.

It is **much** better to explicitely state the format a date is in by using the `to_date()` method:

```
to_date('2013-09-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or if you want to type a bit less, you can use an ANSI date literal which is specified by using the keyword `DATE`  in front of an ISO formatted string literal:

```
DATE '2013-09-04'
```

Comment: Also: in the `exists` subquery there are references that do not use the table aliases.

Comment: And a missing comma in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: (+1) `Dato salgstrin` is a column too, and you should add a comma to group by

Comment: This changed the error to: "KS_DRIFT"."DIAN_POT_PPR"."Oprettet af Initialer": invalid identifier

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it seems no matter what i do i keep getting that error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ahh i fixed it apprently i had to remove the table name from it so it is 'WHERE    exists (SELECT 1 FROM KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO WHERE KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO.INITIALER = "Oprettet af Initialer" )'

Answer (score 0):

You are using the single quote `'` that is used to mark strings instead of using double quotes `"` that is used when column/table names have spaces or are reserved names like `USER` or `INDEX`. Didn't removed `KS_DRIFT` from table names but you should have `TableName.ColumnName` format and not `xxx.TableName.ColumnName`.

This query should work (but you have to fix the `KS_DRIFT` part):

```
SELECT   COUNT(POT."Oprettet af Initialer") AS meetings_booked,
         POT."Dato salgstrin",
         VTEAM.TEAM
FROM     KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR POT 
         RIGHT JOIN KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO VTEAM ON VTEAM.DATO = POT."Dato salgstrin"
WHERE    exists (SELECT 1 FROM KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO WHERE KS_DRIFT.DIAN_POT_OPR."Oprettet af Initialer" = KS_DRIFT.V_TEAM_DATO.INITIALER)
AND      POT."Salgstri" NOT IN('01 - Muligt emne','02 - Aktivt emne')
AND      POT."Oprettet dato" BETWEEN '2013-09-04' AND '2013-09-04'
GROUP BY "Dato salgstrin", "Oprettet af Initialer", VTEAM.TEAM
ORDER BY "Dato salgstrin"
```

To avoid further problems with names with spaces, i suggest you tu use the `_` character.

Referring to the [Oracle Database Object Names and Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements008.htm):

> Note: Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database
>   object names. These quoted identifiers are accepted by SQL*Plus, but
>   they may not be valid when using other tools that manage database
>   objects.

---

Extra: If I'm not wrong, the column `"Oprettet dato"` is *DATE* type and you should use the `to_date()` function and modify the query using this WHERE clause:

```
AND "Oprettet dato" BETWEEN to_date('2013-09-04','YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2013-09-04','YYYY-MM-DD')
```